# PHP, from PSR-4 project, print all methods of all classes using same namespace

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, psr-4

From a project using the psr-4 convention (a symfony project), I want (just) print all methods of all classes with a specific namespace (theses classes are  located in the same directory)

I do some tries with the documentation here https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md but I failed and don't really understand how this lib works (maybe my poor english skills ? :/ )

Someone can help me ?

My last try :

```
class myUtils{

    public function getAllMethods(){

        $loader = new ClassLoader();
        $loader->loadClass('App\DIR1');
        $loader->register();

        // Faa and Foo are the name of the classes of the file Fii.php and Faa.php located in DIR1 directory, the namespace of theses classes is App\DIR1
        if (class_exists("Foo") && class_exists("Faa")){
            dump('Its OK !');
        }else{
            dump('its NOT OK');
        }

        // the dump "Its NOT OK" is printed, I don't find how I can load dynamically Faa and Foo classes..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just play with `ClassLoader::getClassMap()` and you have no other way, cause class will be loaded only when you try to use it. You must filter classes by you custom function.

Any way if you have no predefined list of classes a solution will be dirty.

For methods use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php), it's easy.